# How do you include a raw, uncompiled partial in dust.js?

Tags: dust.js

I have dust working reasonably well, but I'd like to be able to include a file, such as a css file, without compiling and rendering it.

It seems like maybe I need to create an onLoad handler that loads the file and registers the content directly.

Is there a way to do this within dust already?

Comment: You're on the right track. Instead of using the onload handler, which compiles whatever you feed to it, try writing a custom helper instead that uses `chunk.write`. I'll be able to set up an example later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take advantage of Dust's native support for streams and promises to make file inclusion really nice. The exact implementation depends on whether you're running Dust on the server or the client, but the idea is the same.

Write a helper that loads the file and returns a Stream or Promise for the result. Dust will render it into the template asynchronously, so doing file I/O won't block the rest of the template from processing.

For simplicity, I'll write a context helper, but you could also make this a Dust global helper.

```
{
  "css": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    // Do some due diligence to sanitize paths in a real app
    var cssPrefix = '/css/';
    var path = cssPrefix + context.resolve(params.path);
    return $.get(path);
  }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
{#css path="foo/bar.css"}{.}{/css}
```

Or a streamy version for the server:

```
{
  "css": function(chunk, context, bodies, params) {
    // Do some due diligence to sanitize paths in a real app
    var cssPrefix = '/css/';
    var path = cssPrefix + context.resolve(params.path);
    return fs.createReadStream(path, "utf8");
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a great solution and much more flexible than what I did.

I solved it by pre-loading the files I needed into an array in the context (asynchronously, but in a batch) and then injecting with a #css section. I'd just grab everything in my specified directory and inject them, with a global toggle to either embed or add an HTML element with a source tag. That toggle's been handy for debugging.  

I ended up building a an asset packager, which was probably overkill. But it seemed easier than evaluating the asset packagers and task managers out there and learning how to make one work.